# Textbox not allowing letters and showing NaN

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have a textbox that is currently being filled automatically by a function if left empty, however when edited with anything but numbers it changes to "NaN" even though I haven't specified anywhere that it's not allowed to be anything but numbers. It's nvarchar(30) in the database and the input type is set to text. So I have no clue why it's forcing it to be a number. Here's the code for the textbox.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="left:0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="left:0">
                    <div class="MatrixLabel">@ViewData["ArticleOrderNr"]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8" style="left:0">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Txb_ArticleOrderNr" class="textBox" onchange="DescChanged()"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the definitions of both "Txb_ArticleOrderNr" and "ArticleOrderNr":

```
public string Txb_ArticleOrderNr { get; set; }
// This is what ArticleOrderNr is based on
public String bestelNr { get; set; }
```

I have no clue why anything but numbers is turned into "NaN" when typed into the box.

**EDIT:**
As requested, DescChanged():

```
function DescChanged() {
            desc = document.getElementById("Txb_Description");
            input = document.getElementById("Txb_WebArtName");
            kortinput = document.getElementById("KortBesc");
            langinput = document.getElementById("LangBesc");
            merk = document.getElementById("Brand");
            bestelnr = document.getElementById("Txb_ArticleOrderNr");

            if (merk.options[merk.selectedIndex].text == "--") {
                input.value = desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
            }
            else {
                input.value = merk.options[merk.selectedIndex].text + " " + desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
            }
            if (inputoldkort || isEmptyOrSpaces(kortinput.value)) {
                kortinput.value = desc.value;
            }
            if (inputoldlang || isEmptyOrSpaces(langinput.value)) {
                langinput.value = desc.value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you add the DescChanged function logic?

Comment: @MaartenDev Added.

Comment: Could you add `console.log`s to the `if/else` logic to determine which part of the function is executed? Could you describe what the value of `merk.options[merk.selectedIndex].text` is?

Comment: @MaartenDev Well the DescChanged function doesn't edit the Textbox that is the issue, the only thing that function does is change a different textbox to be made up of the value of several different fields, namely Merk, BestelNr and Omschrijving. ```merk.options[merk.selectedIndex].text``` is the text value of the selected DropDownList item.

Comment: Hi @TimVerhees, I think you need share enough code that could reproduce your issue.